# How would you efficiently retrieve the first set of positions for the current day given the above table in a large data set

Tags: sql, data-retrieval

There is a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE[Positions](
            [load_id]           [int]                  NOT NULL, 
            [acct_cd]         [varchar](20)   NOT NULL,
            [acct_num]      [varchar](255)             NULL,
            [sec_id]            [varchar](50)   NOT NULL,
            [long_sht_cd]   [varchar](3)     NOT NULL,
            [sedol]              [varchar](15)   NULL,
            [isin]                 [varchar](15)   NULL,
            [cusip]              [varchar](9)     NULL,
            [sec_type]       [varchar](8)     NULL,
            [sec_name]     [varchar](100)NULL,
            [currency_cd] [varchar](3)     NULL,
            [total_holding] [decimal](18, 4)NULL,
            [mkt_price]      [float]               NULL,
            [datetime_stamp] [datetime]   NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_Positions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(       
[load_id] ASC, 
            [acct_cd] ASC, 
            [sec_id] ASC,
            [long_sht_cd] ASC )
)
```

This table holds account positions data that are appended to multiple times a day 
There are currently some 24 million rows in the table. Every time we append additional positions we add approximately 32,000 entries to this table, and all 32,000 entries will have the same load_id. The load_id is incremented by one each time we load a batch of 32,000 entries (i.e. the first 32K entries have load_id=1, the next 32K has load_id=2, etc...). The datetime_stamp field shows the time at which the entries were loaded and is the same for all 32K entries in a single load.

How would you efficiently retrieve the first set of positions for the current day given the above table definition?

Example:
Today, positions were loaded into this table at 8am, 10am and 3pm.  At 5pm today we want to know what positions were loaded at 8am since that is the first load that occurred today.  Note that for any given day, there can be different number of loads and the times that the loads occur will vary.

Comment: can you add some sample data. INSERTs possibly.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, dense_rank() over (order by datetime) as seqnum
      from positions p
      where p.datetime >= @date and p.datetime < @date + interval '1 day'
    ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is pretty database agnostic.

In SQL Server, you might find that this is best:

```
select top (1) with ties p.*
from positions p
where p.datetime >= @date and p.datetime < dateadd(day, 1, @date)
order by p.datetime;
```

An index on `positions(datetime)` will work, but perhaps more for the `where` than for the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have date time stamp field, but there's no index on it and I assume you mostly interested in the last day (two days) data. In this case what you may want to have is a positions day (new `DATE` type field) and build index on this `Positions Date` and `load_id`. Then you can efficiently query for records as of particular date and batch load (intraday).

Answer (score 0):

You have a reduncandy in your table, since load_id determines datetime_stamp. consider keeping a load table with datetime_stamp, and just use the load_id in the table.

For SQL Server this'll work, for other RDBMS's change the datatype work. I just trim the hour off the from the current date. I PL/SQL this ca be done a lot prettier

```
select *
from Positions
where datetime_stamp=(select min(datetime_stamp) from positions where datetime_stamp between 
cast(CAST(GETDATE() as date) as datetime2) and 
dateadd(MS,-1,cast(dateadd(day,1,CAST(GETDATE() as date)) as datetime2))
)
```